# Cufon is messing up my transparent PNG backgrounds

Tags: css, background, transparency, cufon

I have a few divs with a repeating background PNG (that as an alpha channel set to ~50% opacity); the purpose is to give a white transparent background to the divs. The divs render great in all current browsers. But when I call my Cufon code to replace certain text on the screen, the backgrounds seem to fade out in a gradient fashion from top left to bottom right (in IE only). It doesn't seem to effect all PNG backgrounds, just certain ones.

Something with Cufon is definitely getting in the way of rendering the transparent PNGs. Has anyone ever seen this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cufón wasn't causing the problem; it was just masking it. The real problem was the fact that I was using transparent .pngs that  were 1px x 1px. IE will render them incorrectly and fade them out; almost as if they were being stretched beyond limit.

Comment: You have to make sure that any transparent png you're using is larger than 1x1 px. I haven't tested at what size it starts to work, but 10x10 px is what worked for me, and what seems most people suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I used cufón 18 months ago but that was for headings and labels over white or colored background so I can't help you on this one.
If I had a similar need today, I'd use **@font-face** as Fx3.0 and others are disappearing very fast, being replaced by Fx3.5+ and other recent browsers. Do you have a constraint that prevent you from using this IE-compatible feature?

A few questions if it can be of any help:

- do these elements have hasLayout (with `zoom: 1;` if they don't already have a width, height, ...) or their parents.
- is it always the same elements that work and don't work?
- what happens if you replace one background displaying OK with another that isn't OK? Is this the same element that have a problem or the same background or does something else happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use a larger background image - 10px X 10px or more.